# How to obtain openshift dns address for my application?

Tags: dns, openshift

I have a domain in home.pl service.
Now I have www content in frame.

Code from web browser:

```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
> <HTML><HEAD><TITLE></TITLE></HEAD> <FRAMESET ROWS="*"><FRAME NAME=997
> NORESIZE SRC="http://example.rhcloud.com"> <NOFRAMES><BODY><A
> HREF="http://example.rhcloud.com">click
> here</A></BODY></NOFRAMES></FRAMESET></HTML>
```

I need to redirect **from the www.mypage.com** **to openshift application example.rhcloud.com**, but I need **DNS address** of my application, because I need to put it in admin panel of home.pl service.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The rhc app show  command will show you the url of your application on OpenShift, or you can view your application in the web console and it will show it in the top left area.

Comment: I know how to get my application URL, but I need a DNS server address, for redirection.